# Package manager doesn't work anymore

Tags: 10.10, apt, package-management

I'm using ubuntu 10.10 and recently my package manager has stopped working because of some problems with dependencies or something. I can't upgrade, install or uninstall anything at all. This is a huge problem. I couldn't find a solution to this with google so I'm asking here for help.

This is what apt-get -f install outputs

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  firefox-4.0-core
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b20-1.9.5-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java doesn't exist.
dpkg: error processing openjdk-6-jre-headless (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-6-jre-headless
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just reinstall the package...

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-6-jre-headless.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-6-jre-headless.postinst.bad
sudo apt-get --reinstall install openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

Comment: After all it was that easy. Thank you and thousand internets to you. :D

Comment: "...thousand internets to you." - huh, do you want all spam on the internet to be send to him? :P I've never heard of this saying.

Comment: Feel free to rank up arrange's answer (you've already marked it answered).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a broken Java installation.

Try `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-jre`.

Then I'd recommend ticking the "Partners" repository in synaptic, reloading and installing Sun's JRE with `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre`.

Comment: See my initial post. This is what I did.
But i'll try to roughly translate it.

Comment: Don't translate it, just run it using `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: Everything I do that is either purge, install, upgrade or remove gives me the same error. I can't do anything. It makes the package manager useless.