# apt-get fails to upgrade, install, remove etc

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, software-center, dpkg

I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04, had no issues that I noticed. Recently tried to install something via software center, but it was throwing errors. Changed to trying to `sudo apt-get install` instead but again no luck. I've genuinely tried as much as I know to fix this, but I can't so I figured I'd ask here.

I've done `sudo apt-get update` successfully but `sudo apt-get upgrade` failed with...

```
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 but it is not installed
 libqt4-dbus:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-declarative:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-designer:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-network:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-opengl:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-script:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-sql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-svg:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-test:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-xml:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0~) but it is not installed
 libssl1.0.0 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0:i386 (!= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2) but 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 is installed
 libssl1.0.0:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0 (!= 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6) but 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Using `sudo apt-get -f install`...

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkhtml3.14-19 libglade2-0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqtcore4:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libqtcore4:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl1.0.0:i386
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
20 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,063 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,044 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get remove libssl1.0.0` and `sudo apt-get remove libssl1.0.0:i386`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libcurl3:i386 : Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-dbus:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-declarative:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-designer:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-network:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-opengl:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-script:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-svg:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-test:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xml:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0~) but it is not going to be installed
 libsasl2-modules:i386 : Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've also tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get autoremove` etc without any luck.

I also tried to download the `.deb` and use `dpkg -i`, but that failed and did not fully understand the method to be honest.

**Edit**
This is in response to the comments

ref: [sudo apt-get install -f doesn't fix broken packages. And now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96129/sudo-apt-get-install-f-doesnt-fix-broken-packages-and-now)
`sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-all`

```
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:amd64 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:i386 is in a different version (1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6)
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: also configuring `libssl1.0.0:i386' (required by `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386')
dpkg: error processing libssl1.0.0:i386 (--configure):
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2)
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.0.0
 libssl1.0.0:i386
 ...
 libssl1.0.0:i386
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

Ref: [Package manager doesn't work anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26389/package-manager-doesnt-work-anymore)
moving `/var/lib/kpkg/info/libssl..`

```
kieran@kieran-EX58-UD3R:~$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:i386.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:i386.postinst.bad
kieran@kieran-EX58-UD3R:~$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:amd64.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/libssl1.0.0:amd64.postinst.bad
kieran@kieran-EX58-UD3R:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl' has no installation candidate
kieran@kieran-EX58-UD3R:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install libssl1.0.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-dbus:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-declarative:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-designer:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-network:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-opengl:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-script:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-svg:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-test:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xml:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0~) but it is not going to be installed
 libssl1.0.0 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0:i386 (!= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2) but 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
 libssl1.0.0:i386 : Breaks: libssl1.0.0 (!= 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.6) but 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
kieran@kieran-EX58-UD3R:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkhtml3.14-19 libglade2-0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqtcore4:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libqtcore4:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl1.0.0:i386
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
20 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,063 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,044 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libssl1.0.0 i386 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.2 [1,002 kB]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libqtcore4 i386 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 [2,061 kB]
Fetched 3,063 kB in 4s (731 kB/s)         
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
```

ref: [libssl Dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140510/libssl-dependencies)
removing libssl1.0.0:i386

```
kieran@kieran-EX58-UD3R:~$ sudo apt-get remove libssl1.0.0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libcurl3:i386 : Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-dbus:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-declarative:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-designer:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-network:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-opengl:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-script:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-svg:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-test:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xml:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0~) but it is not going to be installed
 libsasl2-modules:i386 : Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Thanks for posting such a detailed list of what you've tried with accompanying output, it saves a lot of time :).  At the bottom you said you didn't fully understand the method, did you mean the method of installing the program using `dpkg -i`? Also, can you include the output from trying to install the program using `dpkg -i`?

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/96129/sudo-apt-get-install-f-doesnt-fix-broken-packages-and-now

Comment: Possibly related, and the top solution looks promising: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26389/package-manager-doesnt-work-anymore

Comment: Kieran, are you using a 64bit version of Ubuntu?  Normally I don't see :i386 on packages unless you're on Ubuntu and installing :i386 stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, unfortunately still no luck. I've edited the post to put in what I've got from trying these. Jeff, I meant I'm not really sure which .deb file I need to download to use `dpkg -i` on. I'm using 64bit, not sure why the :i386 stuff is there :/ could be that I messed up originally trying to fix the problem and used a i386 package instead of amd64.

Comment: Couldn't fix so I backed up and reinstalled

Answer (score 4):

I recently went through a similar situation trying to install `ia32-libs` (et al) and I believe you might be suffering from a similar issue to what I was, even if it's slightly different.

- A long time ago I added the Xorg-edgers PPA. This contains a whole load of bleeding-edge junk for all sorts of packages. Therefore at this point those packages I was using were the newer ones.
- A time later, I got bored of daily updates to X and various drivers. I disabled the PPA.
- Even later, I tried installing `ia32-libs` and found myself in dependency hell.

What was happening was I had a newer version of some package that dpkg was expecting. Rather than downgrading those few packages (as it should probably suggest) it was recommending removing most of the system so that it could remain on the latest version of the X packages.

Fixing it in my case was actually bizarrely simple: I just re-added the PPA I had disabled. After that I could install whatever I liked. This might not be exactly the same for you so be careful.

---

I bumped into this fix completely accidentally. I had forgotten that I might have newer (and now unavailable) versions of some packages. If I had thought ahead I would have remembered another answer I gave a while ago: [How do I revert all packages to their official versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112865/how-do-i-revert-all-packages-to-their-official-versions/112878#112878)

The script is slow but it's nothing if not thorough. Disable all PPAs, `apt-get update`,  `apt-get dist-upgrade` and then use the script to generate a list of things that deviate from the official versions. Purge/reinstall those and you should be able live a happy, dependency-hell-free life.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with broken dependencies when trying to install wine and acroread, and a complaint when trying to install ia32-libs-multiarch, just after upgrading to 12.04 from 11.04 (passing over 11.10). It seems that some ppa's I had in 11.04 installed newer versions of applications in the system. After upgrading, the remains of these apps seemed to do some mess in the dependencies.

The solution that seems to work (until now), was found on a german ubuntu board ([http://forum.ubuntuusers.de](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/paketabhaengigkeit-mit-ia32-libs-kann-nicht-au/2/), posts from user Lasall):

First a downgrade is required and done with the following:
create the 'preferences' file:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/preferences
```

and insert the following lines:

```
Package: *       
Pin: release a=precise*
Pin-Priority: 2012
```

Pin-Priority must be greater than 1000.

Then you may downgrade the offending applications with:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then you may install packages that complained about dependencies, like
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`, or `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`.

Finally, you should remove the file you just created:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences
```

because else no new updates would be found.

Hope this helps you too!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting similar error:

> libqt4-scripttools:i386 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.3 cannot be configured
>   because libqt4-scripttools:amd64 is in a different version

The following commands fixed the error:

```
sudo apt-get download libqt4-scripttools:i386
sudo dpkg -i libqt4-scripttools:i386
```